# create tablespace in ASM in oracle rac db

Tags: sql, oracle, tablespace

I want to create tablespace in ASM in Oracle rac db `create tablespace <tablespacexxx>  DATAFILE '+data';`. data is one disk storage. I saw there are multiple disk groups when executing `select * from V$ASM_DISKGROUP`;

There is one disk group called Data and another group called Reco. The voting_files column for the two groups is different. voting_files for Data is set to y, and voting_files for Reco is set no n. I am wondering what are the differences between the two, and can I use either one to create tablespaces?

Comment: +DATA is for datafile and +RECO is logfile(s).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the [assembly] tag is not appropriate here; it's for CPU (and bytecode) assembly languages, like x86 `add eax, [rdi]`.  I don't know Oracle or what ASM means in this context, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't apply.  But not certain, so I'm commenting in case there's some kind of internal query assembly language (perhaps like [tag:monetdb-assembly-language]?) that's relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+DATA` for your datafiles. `+RECO` or `+FRA` should be for the fast recovery area, online redo logs, voting files, and control files.

> The Fast Recovery Area is Oracle-managed disk space that provides a
> centralized disk location for backup and recovery files.

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/haovw/oracle-database-configuration-best-practices.html#GUID-DB511B6A-D220-4556-B31B-18E3D310BA61
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ostmg/create-diskgroups.html#GUID-CACF13FD-1CEF-4A2B-BF17-DB4CF0E1800C

Answer (score 0):

According to the disk group names, DATA is supposed to be contain user data, and RECO is to store the recovery logs. It more like an agreement among the developers and DBAs.
So, your new tablespace needs to placed at DATA.
Voting disks manage information about RAC node membership. You should not use it store any user data.